# Term for program hanging due to unsatisfied promise

Tags: language-agnostic, promise, future

A program has a logic error that causes a promise to never be satisfied (or if you're from Java land, your [Future is never Completed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)). As a result, the program hangs.

It seems like this situation can be generalized to a producer-consumer where the producer forgets/loses something.

**What do you call this situation?** Is there a term or phrase to describe it?

---

I don't feel that deadlock is right because I can't identify a circular dependence (one of the [necessary conditions for deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Necessary_conditions)). Livelock doesn't seem right either because the threads aren't contending for a resource—they just have nothing to do.

I think some people do actually refer to this as deadlock. If someone can convince me that all of the [conditions for deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Necessary_conditions) are actually met in this situation, then I'd consider that a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I think if you "cast" the creation of a promise as acquiring a new exclusive lock, waiting on a promise as attempting to acquire a shared lock on that same resource, and satisfying the promise as releasing the exclusive lock, it will start to look like a deadlock. So I'd probably consider it to be a deadlock, just using slightly different terms.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Is it considered deadlock if one of the threads just "forgets" to release the lock before exiting? (I guess that's a good analogy to draw here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a **Liveness Issue**.

There are several different cases of **Liveness** issues with promises that can arise because of different issues in your code.

[image: Liveness, Image Copyright Mark Miller, placed in public domain.]

<sup>Image taken from [here](http://www.erights.org/elib/concurrency/event-loop.html)</sup>

#### Deadlock

In case there is **resource contention** and two or more promises hold resources that the other promise needs to progress and does not release them. This happens when there is **locking**. For example promise returning function P1 holds a [mutex](https://gist.github.com/kriskowal/9122872) for resource A and P2 holds a mutex for resource B. In order to progress P1 needs to take the lock for A and in order to progress P2 needs to take the lock for A - so neither can progress and release the lock. The program comes to a stop.

```
var aPromise = Promise.resolve(); // empty promise
var bPromise = Promise.resolve(); // empty promise
function lockedResourceA(user){
   return aPromise = aPromise.then(user);
}
function lockedResourceB(user){
   return bPromise = bPromise.then(user);
}
```

Now, let's cause a deadlock:

```
lockedResourceA(function(a){
    return lockedResourceB(b){
        // do computation
    });
});

lockedResourceB(function(a){
    return lockedResourceA(b){
        // do computation
    });
});
```

Here it is possible that the computation will never progress.

#### Livelock

> An infinite loop prevents this incarnation of a vat from ever again making progress, just as it would prevent a conventional thread from making progress. As with conventional threads, it does not prevent other vats (threads) from making progress. Unfortunately, since each E object is in only one vat, livelocking a vat does lock up all objects within a vat. (This would be analogous to livelocking a thread that holds a synchronized lock on several objects.)

<sup>[source](http://www.erights.org/elib/concurrency/event-loop.html)</sup>

This is similar to a deadlock, only instead of the promises saying "stuck" each tries to yield the next resource. For example imagine in the example above the promise returning functions don't care which resource they get first - so both P1 and P2 try to yield one resource each time, so they each get one alternating resource and neither gets completed since at each turn each of them holds exactly one item.

#### Datalock

This is a recursive data definition with no bottom - for example a promise that depends on itself or several promises that depend on eachother recursively for fulfillment.

For example:

```
var p = Promise.resolve().then(function(){ 
    return p; // datalock
});
```

[Here is a full wrap up of this problem](http://www.erights.org/elang/concurrency/epimenides.html)

#### GridLock

> Technically, this looks like a classic deadlock, but it's caused specifically by lack of outgoing buffers. The distinction between deadlock and gridlock? If more buffer space would have caused you not to have locked up yet, then it's gridlock rather than deadlock.

<sup>[source](http://www.erights.org/elib/concurrency/event-loop.html)</sup>

This happens when you're buffering in a promise queue and the insufficient buffer space is preventing progress. This is very related to stream backpressure issues.

#### Lost Signal

This happens when you have a promise but do not fulfill it or break it.

> An example, due to Mark Seaborn (thanks!): If you have a when-catch "waiting" (posted as a callback) for a promise to be resolved, but in the code that's supposed to resolve it, you forget to call `resolve` in all applicable cases. Of course, actual lost signal bugs may be arbitrarily more complicated than this.

<sup>[source](http://www.erights.org/elib/concurrency/event-loop.html)</sup>

For example:

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    // never call resolve
});
p.then(function(){
    // never runs
});
```

Here is [an excellent summary on the topic](http://www.erights.org/elib/concurrency/event-loop.html) by Mark S. Miller.

Comment: Of course, a `getRessource()` function could return a promise that never resolves *due to* a deadlock…

Comment: You described the equivalence between an unsatisfied promise and a future with a diverging computation, but I wanted a term or phrase to describe the bug. If I told a coworker "the program has a never-halting function," I don't think that would be helpful—and a lot of people would probably say it's not even accurate.

Comment: @DaoWen I talked to Mark Miller - the correct term is a "lost signal". I'm rewriting this answer. Mark referred me to an excellent and concise summary on the topic here http://www.erights.org/elib/concurrency/event-loop.html

Comment: Also, I don't think you have permission to post that image here. Note at the bottom of every page how it says `site design / logo © 2015 stack exchange inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required`. That means that when you post anything here, the you're agreeing to those licensing terms. Since that diagram is from Mark Miller's page, I doubt you have the right to re-license it.

Comment: @DaoWen I'm glad you care - I of course checked first. The diagram is listed as public domain - as you can see at the bottom of that page: `Unless stated otherwise, all text on this page which is either unattributed or by Mark S. Miller is hereby placed in the public domain.` . Since that license is much more permissive I'm actually allowed to post it here (with attribution, of course).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Ah—most people don't even realize there's a license agreement involved with posting here. I guess I should have known a 60k+ rep user would know that though. You might ask Mark if he'd be willing to update those footers so that it says "text **and figures**" instead of just "text."

Comment: @DaoWen good idea, I've sent him a link to this post anyway, I'll ask. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for taking the time to write such a detailed response! I'm going to hold off on accepting for a couple of days (on the off chance that someone else might come along and have another amazing answer)—but I'm guessing this is probably the best explanation I'll get. Thanks again!